# Linux: tell if file was opened with O_SYNC

Tags: lsof, linux

Is there a way to tell if a process opened a file with the O_SYNC flag?  I'm thinking lsof might be able to do this, but cannot find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using a `systemtap` script. This one has been taken from [here](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/WSListFlags), and does exactly what you want:

```
# list_flags.stp
# Copyright (C) 2007 Red Hat, Inc., Eugene Teo 
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
# published by the Free Software Foundation.
#

%{ 
#include <linux/file.h>
%}

function list_flags:long (pid:long, fd:long) %{
        struct task_struct *p;
        struct list_head *_p, *_n;

        list_for_each_safe(_p, _n, &current->tasks) {
                p = list_entry(_p, struct task_struct, tasks);
                if (p->pid == (int)THIS->pid) {
                        struct file *filp;
                        struct files_struct *files = p->files;
                        spin_lock(&files->file_lock);
                        filp = fcheck_files(files, (int)THIS->fd);
                        THIS->__retvalue = (!filp ? -1 : filp->f_flags);
                        spin_unlock(&files->file_lock);
                        break;
                }
        }
%}

probe begin {
        flag_str = ( (flags = list_flags($1, $2)) ? _sys_open_flag_str(flags) : "???");
        printf("pid: %d, fd: %d: %s\n", $1, $2, flag_str)
        exit()
}
```

Two examples on how to use it are provided in the referenced link, I'll reproduce one of them here:

```
[eteo@kerndev ~]$ stap -vg list_flags.stp $$ 3 2>&1 | grep O_DIRECT
pid: 30830, fd: 3: O_RDONLY|O_APPEND|O_CREAT|O_DIRECT|O_DIRECTORY|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE|O_NOATIME|O_NOCTTY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_NONBLOCK|O_SYNC|O_TRUNC
```

You can replace `O_DIRECT` with `O_SYNC` for your purpose.

Further references:

- [SystemTap Beginners Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/index.html)
- [SystemTap Tapset Reference](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/SystemTap_Tapset_Reference/index.html)

#
#
#
#
#
#

Comment: Awesome, I didn't now about this tool!  I had to edit your post as some of the characters were being escaped by serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

`lsof +fg /path` will show flags used to open the file provide as a path. The short description of the flags returned can be found in man lsof.